# Ajax e link como fazer com que funcione o a:visited quando se usa ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Fiz um site recentemente esta semana, vhtvshows.com.br.
Quando se clica em alguma série para assistir e escolhe o episódio o ajax pega o link e coloca na minha div, porém quando eu volto o link acessado não fica na cor que coloquei no CSS:

```
#exemplo a:visited{
color:#0099ff;
}
```

Já quando eu abro o link em nova aba aonde o ajax não ira surtir efeito funciona perfeitamente o `a:visited`.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer para que valide o `a:visited` mesmo usando ajax ? não quero ter que usar " iframe".

Comment: Você precisária fazer o ajax carregar de baseado na url, usando uma hash como [nesse site](http://www.pauletsconsorcio.com.br/#!/quem-somos). Repare que ao trocar de página é carregado com ajax, porem a url tbm troca, e quando você entra em uma url diferente diretamente o conteudo correto já é carregado... fazendo o site dessa forma você consegue usar o a:visited

Comment: O blz cara acho que usar o $_GET vou ter o resultado esperado pois vai ser carregado no historico do computador fazendo assim o a:visited funcionar. Obrigadão ai.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não acho que seja possivel, pois o :visited só irá funcionar para os sites que estão presentes no historico do navegador.

Porém você ainda pode adicionar uma classe aos links visitados.

Caso o browser suporte html5, você pode utilizar objeto history para forçar que o link do AJAX entre no historico:

```
var linkOpen = document.getElementById("<ID do seu Link>");
var hrefAtual = window.location.href;
history.pushState(null, null, linkOpen.href);
history.pushState(null, null, hrefAtual);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4eerv7cc/4/)

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo de oque fazer neste caso sem usar visited ? obbrigado

Comment: Poderia fornecer a origem da informação que fala sobre a depreciação do :visited?

Comment: @Guilhermenascimemto, procurei aqui, mas não achei, o que achei foi que alguns elementos do foram depreciados no HTML4 em favorecimento dos do CSS, possivelmente eu assimilei está informação de forma errada.

Comment: @Gabriel, você o link está no mesmo domínio? Pode ser uma solução baseada em HTML5?